# Translating strings python script

Tags: string, translation, translate

is it possible to translate strings of a Python script?
Example: from English to Italian or from English to Francais...
Another detailed example:

```
print("My string")
```

English user will see `My string` while an Italian will see `La mia stringa` and a Francais user will see `Ma corde`

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with [Gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html), thanks to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams).
I followed [this guide](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/20/translate-your-python-3-program-with-the-gettext-module/) to understand how to use this module.

Comment: You may provide additional details.